# Where should I put alembic's generated folder?

Tags: python, fastapi, alembic

I'm starting a fastapi project, and using sqlalchemy + alembic to manage the sqlite db. Everything worked fine till alembic.

Here's the project folder structure:

```
app/
  - api/
  - core/
    - __init__.py
    - settings.py
  - db/
    - __init__.py
    - database.py
```

(I put a `__init__.py` in all folders)

At first, I tried to create migration folder inside `db/`, but with no success (same error as below). So I did `alembic init migrations` in root folder `app/`.

Now the folder looks like:

```
app/
  - api/
  - core/
    - __init__.py
    - settings.py
  - db/
    - __init__.py
    - database.py
  - migrations/
    - versions/
    - env.py
  - alembic.ini
```

And I modified the `env.py`:

```py
from ..db.database import Base
from ..core.settings import settings

target_metadata = Base.metadata

def get_url():
    return settings.db_url
```

Then in `app/`, I tried

- `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "init"`
- `python -m alembic.config revision --autogenerate -m "init"`

But all complained:

```
...
  from ..db.database import Base
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

And since we have `prepend_sys_path = .` in `alembic.ini`, so imports like `from db.database import Base` would work. However I used relative imports in `db/database.py` and `core/settings.py` and all other files too and don't want to modify the codes.

My questions are:

- Maybe I could put the migration folder outside the `app/` and change relative import to `app.db.database`?
- this might work for a single top level app, but what if I have several sub applications (`app/subapps/sub1`, `app/subapps/sub2`), and want to manage separated sqlite file for each sub application?
- or maybe `alembic` is just not the right choice for my use case?

Comment: Have you tried ```from db.database import Base
from core.settings import settings``` ? You're in the root folder and thus going one step above is not possible, thus the error

Comment: `alembic init` will handle that for you, just make sure to configure `env.py` according to the documentation and you project structure.